# If derivative is bounded then exists a differntiable function which is also bounded.

Tags: calculus

**Question**
If $f$ is defined in $[a.b]$ and $f(a)=0, f(b)=1, \forall t \in (0,1)\exists x \in (a,b) :f(x)=t$ then exists a differentiable function $F \in [a,b] s.t. \forall x \in [a,b]: F'(x)=f(x)$.
Prove or give a counter example. (We haven't studied integrals yet)

**Thoughts**
We think the statement is not true, but are having hard time finding a counterexample.
We tried some elemtary functions such as abs, cos and ln, with no success..

Comment: Have you seen [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)?

Comment: If $f$ is not required to be continuous, then define it from $a$ to the midpoint $m$ of $[a,b]$ to go linearly up to $1$, and between $m$ and $b$ let it be any non-integrable function.

Comment: David Mitra - Yes , but isn't Darboux working on the opposite direction?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\cases{{2(x-a)\over b-a} ,& $a\le x\le (b-a)/2$\cr0, &$(b-a)/2<x< b$\cr 1,&$x=b$}$.

Then $f$ satisfies your hypotheses, but $f$ is not the derivative of any function, since it does not have the Intermediate Value Property on $[a,b]$. Derivatives have this property by [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

Comment: The intermediate value property of derivatives is not emphasized properly in calculus. But as in this case this property is one of the simplest techniques to prove that some function does not have an anti-derivative.